# jquery - Redo on the old values

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

[Solved]

This script work good during first run. During run second, third etc. script first display old values var `wartosc` and late display new value var `wartosc` (`uwaga('notice',wartosc);`). 
I think that I should somehow close function, but I don't think as :D.

```
$(function() {
    $("#player").on('click', 'img', function() {
        var zadanie = $( "input[name^='act']:checked:enabled" ).val();
        var wartosc = $(this).attr('value');
        var kupka = $('.kupka').attr('value');
        switch(zadanie){
        case '2':
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            $('.wybor').click(function (){
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
                var ukryta = $(this).attr('value');
                uwaga('notice',wartosc); // my own function like alert :D
            })
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you are registering a click handler inside another one... it is not the right way

Comment: Right, I'll use a reference variable, and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the click handle is bound in another handle, it may be bound more than once. You should unbind click event before you bind the new click handle.

`$('.wybor').unbind('click').click(function (){...`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.attr('value')` you're getting the value from the HTML, not the current value of the input if it has changed. Use `.val()` for that:

```
var wartosc = $(this).val();
var kupka = $('.kupka').val();
```

Comment: No, It works. My image look in html <code><img class="wybor" src="images/cards/1c.gif" value="1"></img></code>

Comment: Your English is poor, I think I misunderstood the question.